vscode "ssh mode" on the CLI
Many of us have experienced the cool "remote mode" of vscode, that lets you work with your local editor (with its settings, plugins, etc.) on a remote machine. Some of us, however, still prefer working on the CLI, and just cannot be productive with graphical IDEs.
I was wondering, is there some equivalent of the vscode ssh mode for the CLI? Something that would let you "inject" on the remote machine your CLI editor with its settings and tools. Personally, I use the Helix editor but I would imagine it as a stand-alone tool, keeping up with Unix philosophy.
It kind of sounds like a cool but impossible (or maybe dangerous) idea, but I was just wondering if anybody thought about it, and cannot find anything searching around.
